# Computing the most accurate result for: the sum of a list of fixed point nubers

Tags: addition, fixed-point

Lets say you'd have to add some 32-bit fixed point numbers stored in a huge array `L` and you'd like to get the most accurate result as possible. Furthermore, you're not allowed to use anything else than L and the 32-bit fixed point numbers (i.e. you're not allowed to convert them to 64-bit). What would be your approach to get the most accurate result for the sum of the numbers in L?

This would be my current approach noted in sudo code:

```
L = sort(L)
result = 0
lastMax = false -- indicates whether we've extracted the maximum from L last time

while (not empty(L)) and (result not equals +INF or -INF) do:
  current = 0
  if lastMax:
    current = extractMin(L) -- gets and removes minimum from L
  else:
    current = extractMax(L) -- gets and removes maximum from L
  result = safeAdd(result, current)
  lastMax = not lastMax

safeAdd(a,b):
  if a = +INF: return +INF
  else if a = -INF: return -INF
  else: return a + b
```

So I'm alternating between adding the minimum/maximum from the remaining list L in order to stay between the ranges of L. The way how `safeAdd` is implemented shows that once we've crossed the ranges of accuracy (i.e., the result of `a+b` has yielded `+INF` or `-INF` - just as it's done in C) we will not alter the result anymore.

Do you have any suggestions on how to improve the approach?

Sidenote: If we want to be very precise: We further assume that the `+` operation can yield `+INF` or `-INF` which can be represented as fixed point numbers in the programming language. But we assume that the values `+INF`, `-INF` do not occur in `L`. And we ignore the fact the fixed point standard may also have a representation for `NaN`.

Comment: Have you considered [Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm)?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm sorry but I just had to change the question from floating point to fixed point numbers. So that might not be relevant anymore.

Comment: @ndrizza Fixed-point addition is simply the addition of integers, so no error is incurred in this operation (i.e., it is exact) unless there is overflow, which is a somewhat different issue possibly addressable by re-scaling depending on use case. Commonly used fixed-point formats do not provide a representation of infinity.

Comment: Thanks, your point (analogy to integers) about accuracy in terms of least important bits is correct. By most accurate I also meant avoiding overflows in intermediate computations. Lets leave the re-scaling out for now.

Comment: If you need to avoid overflow of a iven fixed-point format, and do not want to re-scale, the only other options I see is to try to change the order of the operations, or select a different fixed-point format (while keeping a total of 32 bits for each fixed-point number, e.g. S15.16 vs S23.8). What is suitable will depend on the specifics of your use case.

Answer (score 0):

If you know, that the result is in range, you don't need to care about overflow or underflow.

Here is an example with 4 bits only to keep it simple

```
7    0111
+1   0001
=    1000 <-- -8 overflow
-1   0001
=    0111
```

If you are not sure, if the result is in range, you need to count overflows and underflows.

For a = b + c

Overflow if b and c are positive and a is negative

Underflow if b and c are negative and a is positive